# Create .ics file with javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, icalendar

I am trying to create an `.ics` file when a user clicks a button.

So far the code I have is

```
msgData1 = $('.start-time').text();
msgData2 = $('.end-time').text();
msgData3 = $('.Location').text();

var icsMSG = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR\nVERSION:2.0\nPRODID:-//Our Company//NONSGML v1.0//EN\nBEGIN:VEVENT\nUID:me@google.com\nDTSTAMP:20120315T170000Z\nATTENDEE;CN=My Self ;RSVP=TRUE:MAILTO:me@gmail.com\nORGANIZER;CN=Me:MAILTO::me@gmail.com\nDTSTART:" + msgData1 +"\nDTEND:" + msgData2 +"\nLOCATION:" + msgData3 + "\nSUMMARY:Our Meeting Office\nEND:VEVENT\nEND:VCALENDAR";

$('.button').click(function(){
    window.open( "data:text/calendar;charset=utf8," + escape(icsMSG));
});
```

This downloads a `.ics` file but when I try to open this in iCal I am told it can not read the file.

Comment: What are the values of start-time, end-time, and Location you're using?

Comment: In the end I used http://addthisevent.com/ A very good and simple plugin.

Answer (score 28):

I used the [ics.js](https://github.com/nwcell/ics.js) solution mentioned by InsanelyADHD.

One problem with the solution was that Chrome did not detect the filetype correctly and tried to open the file as text with the editor.

I changed the download function to open the text simply with:

```
window.open( "data:text/calendar;charset=utf8," + escape(calendar));
```

My fork on Github is [icsFormatter.js](https://github.com/matthiasanderer/icsFormatter)

Regarding the license: I have contacted the original author to include a GPL - after that I will include one too.

Comment: you should probably specify what calendar is. My guess is, it's the result of isc().download('name') ?

Comment: @smartbart24 Does your fork work on iOS? That was an issue with the original one.

Comment: Has the `ical.js` chrome issue been fixed? `icsFormatter.js` is no longer maintained? #2022

Answer (score 10):

There is an open source project for this:

- [ics.js](https://github.com/nwcell/ics.js)

It's 100% JavaScript and worked on all modern browsers except for IE 9 and below.

If you are interested in how they get the files working, you can check their source.  They use the following libraries to perform the heavy lifting:

- [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js)
- [Blob.js](https://github.com/eligrey/Blob.js)

Comment: Since there is no license definded its per default All Rights Reserved. Opened an issue for that.

Comment: @InsanelyADHD this ics.js also doesn't support 6 > safari version.

Comment: The original edition is not well maintained and contains critical flaws. The fork is strong in this one. Use the fork. https://github.com/connorbode/ics.js

Comment: @starlocke Is correct, the original version hardly worked. The question has been updated to point to the same version he commented above

Comment: I've edited this answer to point to https://github.com/nwcell/ics.js which appears to be the original and now-maintained version

Answer (score 4):

You have two colon for the organizer address: "MAILTO::me@gmail.com"

If this does not solve the issue, you will have to show us the full ical stream, as it is received by iCal.

Finally, and assuming that start_time and end_time are using the correct format, for the location field, you may need to wrap lines (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.1)  and escape certain characters (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.3.11). In other words, you may want to look at iCalendar libraries.

Answer (score 2):

ics.js didn't work for me since i was loading the data asynchronously from my database. I then switched to [ical.js](https://github.com/mozilla-comm/ical.js/) combined with the saveAs function from ics.js and it worked. If anyone here is having the same issues, feel free to text me then i will provide an example

Comment: Hi, I am trying to use ics.js and it works fine but the savings part in which some browsers do not save the file while Android system is not catching it so it can not display the choose app menu to select Calendar. I am using FileSaver.js for that. Is there any way to download the file instead of saving it. I think that if the ics file is downloaded the Android will be able to display the choose app menu to add the ics to the Calendar app. Am I wrong on this assumption?

Answer (score 0):

I used [icsFormatter](https://github.com/matthiasanderer/icsFormatter) which was mentioned and by smartbart24. But I was required to support IE down to version 7, so I had to tweak things a little.

To use [icsGen](https://github.com/GameplayJDK/icsGen), my fork of icsFormatter, you have to have php 4 or 5 installed on your webserver.